# Flutter Riverpod multiple streams on separate consumer widgets on same screen not working

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, riverpod, consumer

I have a stateless widget which returns a column of two consumer widgets. Each of these two widgets are consuming 2 different streams from providers, both of which depend on the same another provider. Both streams return different type of data. If I leave only one of the two consumer widgets, everything works as expected. But if I show both, one of them returns error after a 5 second timeout - "Error TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed" (seems random if it's the first or the second one, but usually the second).

Using also Flutter Blue Plus to communicate with BT device
Here's a very simplified version of what my code looks like:

```
// responsePacket here - List<int> converted to specifically to Data1 or Data2 depending on 1st byte
responseStream = _txCharacteristic.value..map(responsePacket).where((it) => it != null).asBroadcastStream()

Stream<T> getStream<T>() => responseStream.where((element) => element is T).cast<T>();

Future<bool> _sendIt(List<int> message) {
  return _rxCharacteristic.write(requestPacket, withoutResponse: false);
}

Future<bool> requestData1() {
  return _sendIt([1]);
}

Future<bool> requestData2() {
  return _sendIt([2]);
}

final streamDataProvider1 = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Data1>((ref) async* {
  Object obj = ref.watch(objectStateNotifierProvider);

  while (obj.data != null) {
    obj.bt!.requestData1();
    Data1 value = await obj.data!.getStream<Data1>().first.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));

    yield value;
  }
});

final streamDataProvider2 = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Data2>((ref) async* {
  Object obj = ref.watch(objectStateNotifierProvider);

  while (obj.data != null) {
    obj.bt!.requestData2();
    Data2 value = await obj.data!.getStream<Data2>().first.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));

    yield value;
  }
});

class _MainScreenData extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _TestStream1(), // Comment out one of these and it works as expected
        _TestStream2(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _TestStream1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final stream = ref.watch(streamDataProvider1);

    return stream.when(
      data: (value) => Text(value.toString()),
      error: (e, s) => Text('Error $e'),
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}

class _TestStream2 extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final stream = ref.watch(streamDataProvider2);

    return stream.when(
      data: (value) => Text(value.toString()),
      error: (e, s) => Text('Error $e'),
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

I found here on SO similar questions, but nothing specifically like my case. I want to watch streams separately in some cases. When I want to use both streams in one widget, I found I can nest `StreamBuilder` widgets and use separate snapshots (didn't try that yet though)

What am I missing, that I get one of the two widgets displaying not completing the `Future`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on `.stream` + `StreamBuilder` to listen to a `StreamProvider`

The correct usage is:

```dart
    final value = ref.watch(streamDataProvider2);

    return value.when(
      data: (value) => Text('$value'),
      loading: () => CircularLoadingProgressIndicator(),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('error $error'),
    );
```

Comment: Still same issue, but now I see the error - one of the two timeouts (I have set to 5 seconds and after indicator spins for 5 secs, it shows the error). And again, one by one they work with your provided approach, but not together

Comment: I've edited a tiny bit my question to clarify how exactly I'm getting stream value from `obj` in both providers

Comment: Your example still uses `.stream` though, and you haven't shared the error

Comment: I've changed in my code as you showed here (didn't edit the question), and the error is "Error TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed". But I think I know what might be happening and this might require a separate question :( This `getStream<Data1>()` is implemented like this: `Stream<T> getStream<T>() => responseStream.where((element) => element is T).cast<T>();` This stream is coming from Flutter Blue Plus `BluetoothCharacteristic` value after I send request to get that data.

Comment: So basically both streams are pinging via UART to get different type of data and right after that, reading the packet. I believe, when both providers request different data from same object, it somehow clashes and packets of different data get lost. Just don't know how to actually test this or how to approach solving :/

Comment: Added much more details to the question